# Cypress has a problem with stub function in the component vue3 composition api?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vuejs3, cypress, vue-test-utils

my stack:

1. cypress
2. @vue/test-utils
3. component in vue3 in composition api (<script setup />)

My test, i would like to spy a method inside a component .

myComponent

```
testView.vue

<template>
    <div class="test" @click="a()">test </test>
<template>
    <script setup>
    function a() {
        // logic 
        b()
    }
    function b() {
        // logic
    }
</script>


test.cy.js
describe('ClientView.vue', () => {
    it('test', async () => {
        const store = createStore({
            state() {
                return {
                    varA: null,
                }
            },
            actions: {
                actionA(context, newMessage) {
                    return Promise.resolve()
                },
            },
        })
        const mockRoute = createRouter({ history: createWebHistory(), routes: [] })
        mockRoute.currentRoute.value.name = 'testUrl'
        mockRoute.currentRoute.value.params = undefined
        const wrapper = mount(testView, {
            global: {
                mocks: {
                    $route: mockRoute,
                },
                plugins: [store, mockRoute]
            },
        })
        const spyA = cy.spy(wrapper.vm, 'a').as('a')
        const stubB= cy
                    .stub(wrapper.vm, 'b')
                    .callsFake((methods, payload) => {
                        console.log('methods', methods)
                        console.log('payload', payload)
                        return true
                    })
                    .as('b')
       

          // simulate click and launch function a()
          // I see in my log, the function A, b  and the action is called
         wrapper.find('test').trigger('click')
        expect(spyA ).to.be.called
        expect(stubB ).to.be.called
       
    })
})
```

My errors

spyA is called ok

```
expected stubB to have been called at least once, but it was never called
```

Id a update my component

```
testView.vue

<template>
    <div class="test" @click="a()">test </test>
<template>
    <script setup>
    function a() {
        // logic 
        // add this but it's not autorize in vue3 in composition api.
        this.b()
    }
    function b() {
        // logic
       
    }
</script>
```

My test work ...

Cypress has a problem with the version of vue3 in composition api ? or i need to declare my stub otherwise ?

thanks for help.